# Is there anyway to make a standalone chrome web app?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, frontend

I'm building a front end interface and I would like it to run as an app instead of a website. However, I'd prefer it to run from a desktop icon and not by opening chrome and launching the app or having any of the chrome UI/address bar etc.

I've read around the chrome docs and it seems you can go full screen but not standalone?

Can you please point me in the right direction, preferably using chrome but I could use another WebKit based renderer if that's the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things have changed a lot in the +-10 years since this was asked, but just to clarify as of 2022...

We now have the option to compile code (in various languages) to WebAssembly, and run that WASM module using a standalone, platform-indepedent runtime like [Wasmer](https://wasmer.io/)
 or [WasmTime](https://wasmtime.dev/).

[This can even be done for JavaScript code itself](https://www.wasm.builders/gunjan_0307/compiling-javascript-to-wasm-34lk), where legacy logic is in JS, making it possible to have older projects run as standalone applications!

Answer (score 2):

You can look at one of the libraries wrapping Webkit, for example Qt has the [QWebView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) widget. A simple Qt application with only this one widget should be what you need, in only some lines of C++:

```cpp
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebView>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWebView view;
    view.load(QUrl("http://my.app.corp"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

The [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/downloads) IDE helps you to compile that into an application binary.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it will do what I need. I'm going to accept it since it does answer the question. Would love to see Google supporting standalone apps in the future.

Comment: I suppose for at least the Mac client, I could do pretty much the same thing in xcode/cocoa and then the rendering would benefit from Apple updates without updating the App?

Comment: Yeah, passing updates is a problem since Windows does not ship Qt by default. On a Linux distribution, this would be a no-brainer since you can usually rely on qt4 being available in the base system. Advantage of Qt: Works across platforms (modulo recompiling). If the disadvantage of no updates is a bigger problem, you can (for Windows) look into the MSDN for how to embed an Internet Explorer window into your application in a similar way.

Comment: I think an out of date webkit based QWebView would probably render better than an up to date Internet Explorer window. ;)

Comment: this no makes sense to me sorry...can you explain more what's qt and language this is in. I have demo chrome app that i'd like to use with nodejs and have it as standalone. what can i do?

Comment: As I said, that is C++. You'd need to compile that once and deploy it to your clients. Node.js won't help you there since your clients don't have a node server standing there, just a desktop box (I presume).